# How to use Gunicorn with Flask

Tags: python, flask, heroku, deployment, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy my flask app at Heroku but I am facing a problem with Procfile.
I was reading an article where there have this as file.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "<h1>Hello, World</h1>"
```

Then in **Procfile** it's like that:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

And it work, Tough me it's not the case, My folder structure is like that:
In **flask_simple_app** *folder*

```
├── run.py
└── simple_app
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── routes.py
    ├── static
    │   └── style.css
    └── templates
        ├── base.html
        └── home.html
```

**run.py** contain following lines:

```
from simple_app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

****init**.py** contain following lines:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from simple_app import routes
```

**routes.py** contain following lines:

```
from simple_app import app
from flask import render_template

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

So my question is to know where I should put ***Procfile*** and how I'm gonna write this:

```
web: gunicorn ...:...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

- `web: gunicorn module_name_where_app_instance_exists:name_of_the_app_instance`

In your case:

- `web: gunicorn run:app`